# emacs jupyter gives *invalid read syntax* error in org mode

Tags: org-mode, jupyter

am trying to execute a simple code block in org mode

```
* a simple trial
#+begin_src jupyter :session py :async no
x = 'foo'
y = 'xbar'
x + ' ' + y
#+end_src
```

I get the following error

```
Code block evaluation complete.
executing Jupyter code block...
error in process sentinel: async-when-done: Invalid read syntax: "#", 17, 1304
error in process sentinel: Invalid read syntax: "#", 17, 1304
```

Changing `jupyter` to `python` and the block evaluates correctly. I have already run `jupyter-connect-repl` as well.

If it's any help, the *emacs* buffer shows this possible error:

```
(fn EVENT)"] (error) nil jupyter-ioloop-stop signal] 6] #[0 "..." [(#s(jupyter-session (:shell_port 47853 :iopub_port 55985 :stdin_port 54941 :control_port 33237 :hb_port 39821 :ip "127.0.0.1" :key "044944fa-4923-48c5-9a39-274d9524ed4b" :transport "tcp" :signature_scheme "hmac-sha256" :kernel_name "python3") "a8558df6-3bbd-4897-a7e1-7a3a945177b0" "044944fa-4923-48c5-9a39-274d9524ed4b")) #s(jupyter-kernel-process #s(jupyter-kernelspec "python3" (:argv ["python" "-m" "ipykernel_launcher" "-f" "{connection_file}"] :env nil :display_name "Python 3 (ipykernel)" :language "python" :interrupt_mode "signal" :metadata (:debugger t)) "/home/roy/.virtualenvs/karpathy/share/jupyter/kernels/python3") #s(jupyter-session (:shell_port 47853 :iopub_port 55985 :stdin_port 54941 :control_port 33237 :hb_port 39821 :ip "127.0.0.1" :key "044944fa-4923-48c5-9a39-274d9524ed4b" :transport "tcp" :signature_scheme "hmac-sha256" :kernel_name "python3") "a8558df6-3bbd-4897-a7e1-7a3a945177b0" "044944fa-4923-48c5-9a39-274d9524ed4b") nil) cl-struct-jupyter-kernel-tags type-of signal wrong-type-argument jupyter-kernel 2 error "A session is needed to connect to a kernel's I/O"] 5] ((:shell (:endpoint "tcp://127.0.0.1:47853" :alive-p t) :iopub (:endpoint "tcp://127.0.0.1:55985" :alive-p t) :stdin (:endpoint "tcp://127.0.0.1:54941" :alive-p t))) (:shell :iopub :stdin) jupyter-session-endpoints nil :endpoint plist-get :alive-p] 9] (nil) #s(jupyter-kernel-process #s(jupyter-kernelspec "python3" (:argv ["python" "-m" "ipykernel_launcher" "-f" "{connection_file}"] :env nil :display_name "Python 3 (ipykernel)" :language "python" :interrupt_mode "signal" :metadata (:debugger t)) "/home/roy/.virtualenvs/karpathy/share/jupyter/kernels/python3") #s(jupyter-session (:shell_port 47853 :iopub_port 55985 :stdin_port 54941 :control_port 33237 :hb_port 39821 :ip "127.0.0.1" :key "044944fa-4923-48c5-9a39-274d9524ed4b" :transport "tcp" :signature_scheme "hmac-sha256" :kernel_name "python3") "a8558df6-3bbd-4897-a7e1-7a3a945177b0" "044944fa-4923-48c5-9a39-274d9524ed4b") nil) #s(hash-table size 3 test eq rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8125 purecopy t data (interrupt 6 shutdown 10 restart 21)) jupyter-interrupt jupyter-shutdown t nil jupyter-restart action] 7 "
```